# How to save data in Hazelcast with more then one kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast

There are lot of tutorials how to use Hazelcast with spring boot in kubernetes for [example](https://dzone.com/articles/hazelcast-with-spring-boot-on-kubernetes)

Problem is we have 2 data centers, A and B. In both there of these data centers there is kubernetes cluster with application and hazelcast cluster. So the question is how should I configure configure application in data center A to save data in both cluster (A is easy according to tutorial) but how to also configure hazelcast in second cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem on two layers:

**1. Application layer** - Your application can store the data in multiple Hazelcast clusters. If you use Hazelcast with Spring Data, then you can configure [multiple databases with Spring JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases). Note however that when your application stores the data in the data centre that is in a different region, then the latency will suffer significantly

**2. Hazelcast layer** - Hazelcast clusters propagate the data changes across multiple data centres using geo-replication ([Hazelcast WAN Replication](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-wan/), Enterprise feature); then you connect your application to on Hazelcast cluster only, the one that is co-located with your application.